# how to select multiple static rows with one SQL query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

We all know that:

```
select 1,2,3
```

will give us:

```
|1|2|3|
```

However, what I want to get is:

```
|1|
|2|
|3|
```

I am aware that it can be achieved by "union"s like:

```
select 1 union select 2 union select 3
```

And WITHOUT the temporary table or predefined table.

Is there any better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is basically fine, but you should use `union all`:

```
select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
```

`union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates, and you don't want to do that.

An alternative solution would be to use a `numbers` table, if you have one handy.

Another solution would be to take any sufficiently large table and use:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
limit 3;
```

This is handy if you want to expand to larger numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Your `UNION` version is perfectly fine. As alternative with [MariaDB 10.3.3 or later](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/table-value-constructors/) you can use `VALUES`:

```
VALUES(1),(2),(3);
```

**[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=28e161e637037540f810f9479cfb6d1a)**